# How to manipulate UIButtons via tag

Tags: ios8, swift2

I'm trying to create a simple AI for a tic tac toe game that already allows two players to select from nine invisible buttons. Using sender.tag I am able to set the background of each button to display an 'X' or 'O.'

Now I want to create an AI but I don't know how to set each button background based on the AI selection. I tried to do this through the tag parameter, but it doesn't work because there is no sender.

What's the best way to go about manipulating the background (or any parameter of a UIButton with no name)?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifying UI elements by their tags is not the best practice. If you design your UI with Interface Builder then you can assign those UIButtons to an array of UIButton outlets which then allows you access to necessary object which should be manipulated.

1) Declare an array of outlets:

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

2) Connect in Interface Builder all UIButtons to the buttons outlet in predefined order

3) Use an extension for UIButton to change its color:

```
extension UIButton {
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forUIControlState state: UIControlState) {
        self.setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color), forState: state)
    }
}
```

4) Then refer to the selected UIButton from the outlet array when AI computes the move:

```
buttons[int_of_AI_selected_button].setBackgroundColor(thecolor, forthecontrolstate)
```